# Exclude .Gz File while zipping - Debian Linux

Tags: linux, shell, zip

```
zip -r foo.zip foo/
```

I am using the above Linux command in `putty` which compresses the folder ‘foo’ and all of its contents into a zip file called ‘foo.zip’.

The command works great, I would like to exclude all files in all the subdirectories that have `.gz` file extension.

Is there a command to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--exclude` (`-x`) option:

```
zip -r foo.zip foo -x \*.gz
```